# Jquery form validation issue when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am attempting to create a registration form that uses jquery for validation. When i click submit it doesnt seem to be working, it just lets me add anything into my Database even if there are missing fields or the passwords arent matching.

I have created a fiddle any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/U8dGW/5/

```
if(username == "") {
    $("span.val_username").html("This field is required".).addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
} else {
    $("span.val_username").html("");
}

if(name == "") {
     $("span.val_name").html("This field is required".).addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
} else {
    $("span.val_name").html("");
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Open the console (F12), errors there are, many indeed. (hint: all the  periods that are out of place)

Comment: You should not rely solely on javascript for form validation, NEVER EVER! do some back-end checking.

Comment: Additionally the code is so buggy and missy.. please try to fix it a bit more!

Comment: Cheers Yusaf that helps....

Comment: use firebug to check client side bug if use firefox

Comment: I used the console and got rid of the errors, still doesn't work hmm, i've updated the fiddle, if someone wouldn't mind having a look

Comment: My answer contains a working fiddle in the comment section.. please check it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it seems that your form is submitting because you haven't overriden the onsubmit event so basically you need to put in the form opening tag:

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

this will prevent the form from submitting automatically.. now you need to fix the validation method..

[I fixed most of the bugs here.. you need to look at the validation process itself.](http://jsfiddle.net/U8dGW/4/)

Comment: Please use that version it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/U8dGW/6/ All your problems where with syntax.. such as not writing = after class in the HTML or forgetting if in an if/else block.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, however it keeps telling my emails arent the same when they are :S

Comment: Ok.. fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8dGW/7/ Now it is working.. :-) it was that you put in an if one = instead of == so that override the value of the email making it different from reemail

Comment: Now better than invoking validation onclick you should invoke it onsubmit and return false if validation errors exists.. like here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8dGW/8/

Comment: Thank you so much, im not sure why, but do you know why it is saying every email is invalid, like this hk4oli@gmail.com ?

Comment: I think it's because your regex isn't correct.. try this one: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

Comment: Works thank you, i don't know if you could tell me but for some reason if i use it on my actual browser, i dont get the error messages down the side of the form elements it just doesn't submit the form, could you think of any reason why?

Comment: Can you send me a fiddle please?